# How to copy a file from one windows server to another remote windows server using python?

Tags: python

I connect remote server(via Remote desktop) using username/password.
How can I copy one file from my machine to that remote windows machine using python?

Comment: RDP is not intended to be a file transfer protocol. What other forms of connection do you have?

Comment: @cricket_007 Windows network share.

Comment: @Ratha what is "Windows network share"? You mean a shared folder, SMB?

Comment: Try `pysmb` https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html